# Postgres date from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm having difficulties with getting date format right from PostgreSQL db to NodeJS with the following string:

**const queryStr = 'SELECT TO_CHAR(created_on, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') from database';**

What I get is the following error since I guess node is not interpreting the parameters rigth:

```
C:\[...]\Project\server.js:24
                            'TO_CHAR(created_on, 'DD-Mon-YYYY')'
                                                  ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
```

Also "DD-Mon-YYYY" is not working.
I don't know how to "escape" the TO_CHAR format in order to format the date in the way I want.
Any idea is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Add "\" like this, eg: ' doesn\'t '

Comment: Yes, I should have forgot this among all the combinations I tried.  So right formatting comes with this notation  **TO_CHAR(created_on, \'DD-Mon-YYYY\')**    Thanks a lot @darklightcode